# Ratio of areas (Puzzle)

Tags: algebra-precalculus

The picture shows percentages of areas of disjoint regions of squares.
Find the ratio of the sides of the squares (smaller to larger).

Solution: I found ratio of joint regions $0.5625({27 \over 48})$, and somehow I should manage to find ratio of sides from that, any idea?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let the small square have side $1$ and the large square have side $s$.  The overlap area is $0.48$, which is $0.27$ of the large square.
$$0.48=0.27s^2\\s=\sqrt{\frac{0.48}{0.27}}=\sqrt{\frac {16}9}=\frac 43$$

Comment: I don't understand where you get $s^2$ in $0.48=0.27s^2$

Comment: The area of a square of side $s$ is $s^2$.  $0.73$ of that is disjoint from the other square so the overlap is $0.27s^2$

Answer (score 2):

If $A_o$ is the area of the overlapped region, and $s_1,s_2$ are respectively the sides of the smaller and bigger squares. Then $$\frac{100-52}{100}.s_1^2=A_o=\frac{100-73}{100}s_2^2~\Rightarrow~\frac{s_1}{s_2}=\frac34$$